# purpose of Target Pools in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to GCP and working through some tutorials. In one Qwiklabs tutorial (https://google.qwiklabs.com/focuses/558?parent=catalog) they have us set up a Managed Instance Group, point that to a Target Pool, and then create a Load Balancer and point it to the Target Pool.

What I don't understand is why the Target Pool is necessary. Why couldn't we just point the Load Balancer at the Managed Instance Group? I'm guessing this will become more obvious with experience, but I can't find a simple answer to this question right now.

Comment: Can you share the link of your tutorial? What is its creation date?

Comment: Sure, sorry - I added the link to the question. It doesn't have a creation date but I think probably in the past couple of years since Qwiklabs is new.

Comment: A tarjet pool is necessary when an instance group [receives incoming traffic from forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/target-pools). The link you provided requires signing up to Qwiklabs, people who cannot access the link is not able to understand the context of the lab and most of the times, the labs have an objective that can includes the reason on why a specific service is used. For those ones, we would appreciate you can include the details of the lab

Comment: @Stephen do you have any new insights on this? i am new to GCP and struggling with the same question. to make things complex, pool seem to be optional with addition of "legacy" health checks. (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#create_a_health_check). google engineers know exactly how to make the rest of us feel dumb.

Answer (score 1):

You have to see this aspect from two different point of view, the **network** load balancer needs a set of machines for is forwarding algorithm to direct traffic, it accepts as an item an instance group that is an already defined managed/unmanaged set of VMs.

An instance group instead is a concept more related to computing and how you want to handle a set of machine as "a single entity" during spikes, rolling updates, etc
Instance groups are generic and also used for http/s load balancer backends, not only for target pools.

If you are still confused, have a look at [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/adding-an-instance-group-to-a-load-balancer) and at the [documentation of instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/).

Comment: I understand the purpose of load balancers and instance groups pretty well - my question is basically why we need another layer of abstraction, a "target pool", in between them. What is its purpose?